# Wordcloud using matplotlib is not showing

Tags: matplotlib, databricks, word-cloud

For my code, please see below:

```
#tfids words word cloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import pandas as pd

tf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['word'])

tf['word'] = ['federalist', 'wrexham', 'remy', 'islamic', 'hegseth', 'hereford', 'gbt', 'sharenet', 'cpr', 'vegas', 'krvn', 'bandidos', 'nginx', 'manafort' , 'roth', 'kennedy' ,'pence', 'quantum']

wordcloud10 = WordCloud().generate(' '.join(tf['word']))
plt.imshow(wordcloud10)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("")
plt.show()
display()
```

In databricks, one has to use display to see a chart. Despite the above code, I don't see a wordcloud. The O/p i see as below:

```
Out[1106]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fae917806d0>
Out[1106]: (-0.5, 399.5, 199.5, -0.5)
Out[1106]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7faeb31a6110>
```

Thanks for your help.
[Screenshot from Databricks - No Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IVvX.png)

Comment: your code doesn't work, tf is not defined

Comment: Apologies, Getting used to stack overflow. Added an initialization for tf['word']

Comment: And add `import pandas as pd` (PS. for me it's working)

Comment: Thanks @RobJan. This code may work in a standard ipython notebook. I specifically have issues with databricks. Did you happen to try it in databricks? Thanks.

Comment: this works for me using jupyter notebook, not sure what is going on with databricks

Comment: maybe create a handle for the figure and pass it as an argument for display, i.e `fig = plt.imshow(wordcloud10)` and then `display(fig)`

Comment: Thanks @Yuca. I had tried that prior - unfortunately didnt work. Left a question on databricks forum here: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/15003/wordcloud-using-matplotlib-is-not-showing.html

Comment: this is out of my competency, good luck!